# VB.NET WebBrowser control to capture a portion of the webpage (NOT full page snapshot)

Tags: .net, vb.net, browser, webbrowser-control, snapshot

**Background**

I developing an application in VB.NET which intend to open a website content (using WebBrowser control), take a snapshot of a small portion of the full page (NOT full page snapshot), then save the image into a PNG or JPG file

There are a lot of [coding samples](http://maxivak.com/taking-screenshots-of-websites-with-net-windows-forms/) which allows full page snapshot, but unable to find what I needed, so I start tweak the code myself

**The Problem**

Instead of starting the snapshot at location point x=0, y=0. I need the snapshot starting at coordinate x=100, y=200 with boundary size of 500x300 pixels (towards bottom right direction of starting point). For some reason, my code always snapshot at coordinate x=0 & y=0. Could anyone please help to check what is the problem here?

**My Code**

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
    End Sub

    Private Function FolderExists(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Boolean
        Dim f As New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderPath)
        Return f.Exists
    End Function

    Public Function SaveAsImage(filename As String, x As Integer, y As Integer, width As Integer, height As Integer) As Boolean
        Try
            Dim scrollWidth As Integer = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width
            Dim scrollHeight As Integer = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height

            Debug.Print("scrollWidth = " & scrollWidth & ", scrollHeight = " & scrollHeight)

            'browser size
            WebBrowser1.Size = New Size(scrollWidth, scrollHeight)

            'bitmap size
            Dim bm As New Bitmap(width, height)

            'snapshot browser to bitmap 
            '** no matter what x & y values I entered, final image always starts from point 0,0 **
            WebBrowser1.DrawToBitmap(bm, New Rectangle(x, y, width, height))

            Dim savePath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename)
            If (FolderExists(savePath) = False) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath)
            End If

            'save bitmap to file
            bm.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

            bm.Dispose()

            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception

            Debug.Print(ex.Message)
            Return False

        End Try

    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://cnn.com")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'capture 500x300 pixel PNG file at location x=100, y=100 of the webpage
        SaveAsImage("D:\temp\1.png", 100, 200, 500, 300)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Control.DrawToBitmap() is not supported for ActiveX controls like WebBrowser.  Review existing questions by putting "webbrowser drawtobitmap" in the Search box at the upper right of this page.